# Determining under which Strategy user logged in

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

My app uses Passport with two Strategies: Facebook and Local. Is it possible to determine somehow (some property or state variable) which Strategy the user used to log in to the app (i.e., determine from some information **within** Passport)? Is there some property or other setting in maybe the `req` object that indicates the provider associated with the logged-in user? Would really prefer to get this from Passport rather than setting up my ow variables to keep track of this, if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not provided in Passport directly.  I've done something similar in an app, and just use an extra bit of middleware on the login route to track session-related information, such as what provider was used.  It looks something like:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.loggedInWith = 'facebook';
    next();
  },
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Comment: Good solution. Thanks. Perhaps in some next revision to Passport, you might want to include some kind of baked-in provision to determine Strategy in effect, in the case where multiple Strategies are used, to avoid hacking middleware (simple as it is). Thanks again for your response.